# LFS 7.5 - Glibc-2.19 compile errors at section 6.9, are they fatal to my LFS build?

Tags: linux, compiling, glibc, lfs

I am using a host Ubuntu 14.04 system, and I am currently going through the Linux From Scratch guide here. At section 6.9, http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/glibc.html, after compiling and testing glibc-2.19 I have received the following errors:

```
make[2]: *** [/sources/glibc-build/libio/tst-ftell-partial-wide.out] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libio/tests] Error 2
make[2]: *** [/sources/glibc-build/posix/tst-getaddrinfo4.out] Error 1
make[2]: [/sources/glibc-build/posix/annexc.out] Error 1 (ignored)
make[1]: *** [posix/tests] Error 2
make[2]: [/sources/glibc-build/conform/run-conformtest.out] Error 1 (ignored)
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

A better formatted paste is at pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/qTCM1Rif

So far there was no other issues before this chapter, and I don't think there are any other problems. Can these errors be safely ignored, and what are the causes of these errors?

There might be a timeout factor involved, I am going to retry the tests with:

```
TIMEOUTFACTOR=16 make -k check 2>&1 | tee glibc-check-log
```

To see if the errors will clear up. Will post results when complete

Comment: Log files for the entire build process of almost all the packages are available on their site. You might want to check that the next time.. http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/build-logs/7.5/core2duo/logs/

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late, but no, those errors are totally fine. It even says so in that specific LFS chapter.